# Ext js client request for session active spring

Tags: session, extjs, spring-security

I need to check is session is still active on my client side. Are there any request possible which would not extend the session? I could use then this request to check if session is still active. Please provide suggestion I have no clue how to overcome this.

Comment: What language are you using on server side?

Comment: Do you know how can you check the active sessions in Grail?

Comment: There is a session variable I believe

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` function with ExtJS Ajax request to check active session that you specified time.

```
var checkSession = Ext.Ajax.request({
    // the following url must response a value based on the
    // user session status, long story short
    // you should define a function in Grails
    url: '/grails_url/function',
    method: 'POST',
    success: function (response) {
        Ext.Msg.show({
            title: 'Session Expired...',
            msg: 'You session has been expired!',
            width: 300,
            height: 200,
            closable: false,
            buttons: Ext.Msg.INFO,
            buttonText: { ok: 'OK'},
            icon: Ext.Msg.INFO,
            fn: function(btn) {
                if (btn == 'ok') {
                    window.location.href = 'http://www.domain.com/login';
                }
            }
        })
    }
});

// check session for every 5 sec
setInterval(checkSession, 5000);
```

Comment: Wouldn't the request extend the session every time?

Comment: I have no idea about Grails but you can try other alternatives, like using a cookie, https://github.com/benlucchesi/grails-cookie-session-v2